# How to call an unexported package function?

Tags: go, reflection

How to call an un-exported package function ?

For example this package contains a private function `hello` defined as:

```
package testlib

import "fmt"

func hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello testlib")
}
```

Within the package main, I would like to write:

```
package main

import (
  _ "reflect"

    "testlib"
)

func main() {
    testlib.hello()
}
```

Of course, this program is incorrect.

I have googled much, many people mentioned that the `reflect` package could be used to invoke an unexported function, like:

```
obj := ... (some object)
val := reflect.ValueOf(obj);
fun := val.MethodByName("hello")
fun.Call([]reflect.Value{})
```

But all examples are based on an object (i.e,. a struct), and its methods, not a package function.

Answer (score 10):

You can't. That's the purpose of unexported functions. Only the declaring package can call it.

If you're the package writer, and you need to call it from other packages, then export it. If it's not your package, then don't try to call it. It's not part of the packgage's API, it's an implementation detail and as such it may change at any time (what it does may change, its signature may change, it may get renamed or it might get completely removed at any time).

Comment: Yes, I understand it; there is no normal solution to call this kind of API ,this is what EXPORT means; but in fact if we use reflect package, a struct 's UNEXPORTED API could still be called, it's this way that remind me whether there is similar hack method to call a package's UNEXPORTED API. Thanks

Comment: @Hui There isn't any abnormal way either to call an unexported function from another package.

Answer (score 3):

For example, we need to call the **contains** function from the **strconv** package.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    _ "unsafe"
)

//go:linkname contains strconv.contains
func contains(s string, c byte) bool

func main() {
    fmt.Println(contains("Hello World", 'e'))
}
```

[https://play.golang.org/p/OUx35gwAL8J](https://play.golang.org/p/K9PmMb7qTYb)

[Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/compile#hdr-Compiler_Directives)

P.S. But there is no guarantee that the function name will not change in future releases.

Comment: I tried to use that trick to import https://github.com/golang/playground/blob/master/txtar.go#L80 but it failed complaining that the imported package was a program not a library. : /